# Как найти k-ную по счету самую маленькую разницу между двумя числами из списка?

Tags: python, алгоритм, heap

Дан список чисел t, например [4, 1, 5, 2] и число k, определяющее, какую по счету самую маленькую разницу между любых двух этих чисел надо определить.

То есть find(t,1) даст ответ 1, так как первая самая маленькая разница будет между числами 1 и 2

find(t,3) - 2, между 2 и 4

find(t,6) - 4, между 1 и 5

Пытаюсь сделать с помощью heap, но он почему-то сортирует числа не по порядку.

```
from heapq import heapify, heappush

def find(t, k):
 n = len(t)
 heapify(t)
 result = 0
 print(t)
 r = []
 for i in range(1, n):
  heappush(r, abs(t[i]-t[i-1]))

 print (r)
```

Как можно это решить эффективно?

Comment: 1) heap не сортирует числа, а устанавливает специальный порядок 2) засунутые туда числа  - только часть разностей

Comment: @MBo изначальная идея была посчитать разности только между числами, идущими подряд, а дальше высчитывать в зависимости от k. Но видимо с heap так не получится

Comment: что если: 1) отсортировать числа NlogN 2) посчитать разницы соседних чисел (линейное время, линейная память) 3) отсоритровать разницы (NlogN) или использовать кучу (будет что то типа NlogK) для K минимальных значений

Comment: @tym32167 Разниц будет ~эн квадрат

Comment: @MBo нам же нужны минимальные разницы только, а не все разницы. То есть если мы отсортируем исходную послежовательность из N элементов, то мининимальные разницы будут между соседними элементами, и их будет N-1

Comment: @MBo хотя да, квадрат нам понадобится если K >= N

Comment: @tym32167  1 2 4 8 16 32 - и уже третья разница не между соседними

Comment: @MBo ха, логично. Об этом я не подумал. Надо бы обновить теорию и попрактиковаться, а то теряю хватку :)